# Printing formatted args in a buffer

Tags: format

I have the following function that prints some text in a buffer.  But it is not very flexible because it does not accept a format string as `message` does.  How can I change it so that one can use a format string ?

```
(defun tika-instext (bfname text)
  "Write TEXT to the specified buffer BFNAME.
Make a new buffer if needed.

BFNAME  Buffer Object or the name of a buffer as a string."

  (let ((bfr (get-buffer-create bfname)))
    (with-current-buffer bfr
      (insert text))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply #'format` on a list of args which you retrieve via `&rest args` as demonstrated in the following example:

```el
(defun tika-instext (bfname fmt &rest args)
  "Write ARGS to the specified buffer BFNAME formatted by FMT.
Make a new buffer if needed.

BFNAME  Buffer Object or the name of a buffer as a string."

  (let ((bfr (get-buffer-create bfname)))
    (with-current-buffer bfr
      (insert (apply #'format fmt args)))))
```

Docs:

- [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html)
- [`apply`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html)
- [`&rest`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-List.html)